# How to call show action via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am just looking for a place to start with this question, using Ajax to show content in my index action. I have this controller setup:

```
 class GalleriesController < ApplicationController

 def index
   @galleries = Gallery.all
 end

def show
  @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
end

end
```

I have a gallery located on my index page:

```
<ul id="portfolio-grid">
  <% @galleries.each do |g| %>
  <li class="mix <%= g.category.name %> mix_all">
    <% g.gallery_images.take(1).each do |i| %>
    <%= image_tag(i.photo.url(:gallery_portfolio_home), class: 'open-project') %>
    <a href='<%= gallery_path(id: g.id) %>' class="open-project">
    <% end %>
      <div class="project-overlay">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-3x"></i>
        <span class="project-name"><%= g.title %></span>
        <span><%= g.category.name %></span>         
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

  <!-- Ajax Loaded -->
<div id="project-extended">
  <div class="container">
    <ul id="project-controls">
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="close-project">
          <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="project-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Ajax Loaded -->
```

When I click a image I would like to populate the content of my show page into my div #project-content, at the moment my show page looks like this:

```
<div id="project">
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="project-media">
   <div class="project-slider">
       <ul class="slides">
        <% @gallery.gallery_images.each do |image| %>
          <li><%= image_tag(image.photo.url(:gallery_flexslider)) %>
              <p class="flex-caption"><%= image.gallery_category.name %></p>  
            </li>
        <% end %>
       </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Where would be a good place to start, and what do I need to think about with regards to getting this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do it by `UJS` , for that you need to add `remote: true` in your anchor_tag

```
<ul id="portfolio-grid">
  <% @galleries.each do |g| %>
  <li class="mix <%= g.category.name %> mix_all">
    <% g.gallery_images.take(1).each do |i| %>
    <%= image_tag(i.photo.url(:gallery_portfolio_home), class: 'open-project') %>
    <%= link_to "", gallery_path(g), remote: true %>
    <% end %>
      <div class="project-overlay">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-3x"></i>
        <span class="project-name"><%= g.title %></span>
        <span><%= g.category.name %></span>         
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

For that, we need to add a view file `'show.js.erb'`. Now here are the following code for this file.

```
$('#project-content').html("<%= j render '/galleries/gallery'%>")
```

In the galleries/, we need to create a partial named as `_gallery.html.rb`. And nee to put the content

```
<div id="project">
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="project-media">
   <div class="project-slider">
       <ul class="slides">
        <% @gallery.gallery_images.each do |image| %>
          <li><%= image_tag(image.photo.url(:gallery_flexslider)) %>
              <p class="flex-caption"><%= image.gallery_category.name %></p>  
            </li>
        <% end %>
       </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
```

OR you can do the normal AJAX, that RSB suggested. For that in your show action, you need to add `render layout: false`

```
def show
  @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
  render layout: false
end
```

Comment: amazing answer, thank you so much, ill let you know how it goes

Comment: ok so i have implemented this, but it redirects me to galleries/:id for example

Comment: I guess, remote: true is not executing. When we use remote: true, in html5, it appends data-remote=true in the anchor tag. Please check this in the developer tool and also please check the javascript is enabled in your browser or not.

Comment: ok so got data remote = true within the anchor tag, just nothing happening at the moment when clicking link now

Comment: please check the rails s console, there may be some server side error.

Comment: are you available to chat for ten mins please?

Answer (score 1):

If only ajax then you can use this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/galleries/"+id,
})
```

Comment: will this retrieve the whole page as in assets, headers etc.. or will it only get the content on the page?